# How to add a pagination in a html table using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, pagination

I have PHP snippet that displayed a result in the table row. I'm trying to a pagination at the end of the table with (1 2 3 4 ...10). The minimum row will be displayed every page is 15 only.

But my code is not working. Please help me

```
$results_per_page = 10;
$current = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$start = ($current - 1) * $rows_per_page;
$end = $start + $rows_per_page;
$end = (sizeof($rows) < $end) ? sizeof($rows) : $end;

if (isset($_POST['list_position']) && $_POST['list_position'] != 'Select by Position'){
    $list_position= $_POST['list_position'];
    $result_position= $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT id, submit_time, last_name, first_name, middle_name, mobile_number, email, location, position, message FROM tablename WHERE position= '" . $list_position . "' ORDER BY position ASC", OBJECT));
        echo '<table>';
        echo '<tr>';
        $dir="";
        $file="";
        $optionId = 0;
        echo '<th>Submit Time</th>';
        echo '<th>Last Name</th>';
        echo '<th>First Name</th>';
        echo '<th>Middle Name</th>';
        echo '<th>Mobile Number</th>';
        echo '<th>Email</th>';
        echo '<th>Position</th>';
        echo '<th>Message</th>';
        echo '<th>Resume</th>';
        echo '<th>Processed?</th>';
    foreach ($result_position as $record_s){
        $optionId++;
        //$optionId = $record_s['id'];
        for ($i=$start;$i < $end ;++$i ){
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td id="submit_time">' . $record_s->submit_time . '</td>';
        echo '<td id="last_name">' . $record_s->last_name . '</td>';
        echo '<td id="first_name">' . $record_s->first_name . '</td>';
        echo '<td id="middle_name">' . $record_s->middle_name . '</td>';
        echo '<td id="mobile_number">' . $record_s->mobile_number . '</td>';
        echo '<td id="email">' . $record_s->email . '</td>';
        echo '<td id="position">' . $record_s->position . '</td>';
        echo '<td id="message">' . $record_s->message . '</td>';
        echo '<td id="resumeFile'.$id.'"><a href="' . $dir  . $file . '">Download Resume</a></td>';
        echo '<td id="radioOption><label for="Yes">Yes</label>
                  <input type="radio" id="processedOptionYes'.$optionId.'" name="processedOption" value="Yes" onclick="proccessedCheck('.$optionId.',\'Yes\')"/>
                  <label for="No">No</label>
                  <input type="radio" id="processedOptionNo'.$optionId.'" name="processedOption" value="No" onclick="proccessedCheck('.$optionId.',\'No\')"/></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
            }
        }
        echo '</table>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery pagination one another option if you want to try? https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html Here is datatables link you can easily implements in php.

Comment: I need a pagination in a server side

Comment: Yes, you can also include server side.

Comment: I don't want to use any JS, PHP only in pagination